# MAPI in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, email, .net-core, mapi

I want to open the default email client on the computer with presetted values for from, to, subject, body and attachments.

However, MAPI32.DLL has been deprecated many years ago by Microsoft and does not work with .NET 5 64bit applications.

I allready tried many different things but I cannot come up with a solution.

### What did I try?

- mailto: (doesn't support attachments)
- [SimpleMapi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple-MAPI.NET/) (deprecated and does not work within .NET 5/Core 64bit applications)
- Writing the mail as .eml file and open it with the default mail program

Does anybody else have an idea, how I could achive this?

The target mail client is Tobit David.

Thanks!

Comment: Opening the default email client on the computer. That would work mostly on corporate enviroments where you know what software will be installed on client machines. There are many different email clients out there and there is people that has no email client software in their computers.

Comment: @Cleptus MailKit won't help: That's for handling email directly via IMAP/POP3/SMTP - whereas the OP wants to use `MAPI` which allows the user to interact with their e-mail program... at least during the Windows 98 through Windows 7 days (with desktop Outlook, Outlook Express, etc) - I don't think any of the "modern" Microsoft e-mail clients support or use MAPI besides Office Outlook (and that's hardly "modern").

Comment: @Dai, you are fast, I did delete the comment. OP looks for alternatives to MAPI

Comment: You could still use MAPI from a 64-bit program if you use MAPI via COM's out-of-process support to host the 32-bit MAPI objects, e.g. https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Comment: The default credentials are in the user account under mail settings.  So if you want to send email you can use SMTP with default credentials.  The SMTP setting can vary so you should check the website of the email carrier for the settings.

Comment: @Dai, indeed, a decade ago I used "outlook redemption", a 3rd party MAPI related API. No clue about that "Tobit David" client.